# Redux Range Selector

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm trying to make something like this using Redux Form:

[Age range selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6TcG.png)

The problem is that i have the field age. And I can't get it to have both values (it only stores one value)

```
let options = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; // etc... a lot of ages
  // field is a redux field

   // Minimum
  <select {...age} value={age|| 'select'} multi={true}>
    <option key='default' value='default'>Select</option>
    {                    
      options.map(option => 
        <option key={option}>{option}</option>
      )                 
    }
  </select>

// Maximum
  <select {...age} value={age|| 'select'} multi={true}>
    <option key='default' value='default'>Select</option>
    {                    
      options.map(option => 
        <option key={option}>{option}</option>
      )                 
    }
  </select>
```

I don't want to do this:

```
let options = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; // etc... a lot of ages
  // field is a redux field

   // Minimum
  <select {...minimumAge} value={minimumAge|| 'select'} multi={true}>
    <option key='default' value='default'>Select</option>
    {                    
      options.map(option => 
        <option key={option}>{option}</option>
      )                 
    }
  </select>

// Maximum
  <select {...maximumAge} value={maximumAge|| 'select'} multi={true}>
    <option key='default' value='default'>Select</option>
    {                    
      options.map(option => 
        <option key={option}>{option}</option>
      )                 
    }
  </select>
```

Comment: Check if you pass same field reference to both selects.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to create a component which you use multiple times?

```
// SelectComponent
const { options, field } = this.props;
<select {...field} value={field.value || 'select'} multi={true}>
  <option key='default' value="select">Select</option>
  {                    
    options.map(option => 
      <option key={option}>{option}</option>
    )                 
  }
</select>
```

Then use them like this:

```
const ages = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ];
<SelectComponent options={ages} field={minAge} />
<SelectComponent options={ages} field={maxAge} />
```

If you want to save multiple values in your Redux state you would need 2 places in your state anyway.

Comment: That would be an option. Having two fields would make this really easy. I was trying to do this without the need to have minAge and maxAge (just having 'age')

Comment: But how would you define the range? You could save it as an array or something, but why would you make it so hard?